# Access X509 Certificate store with unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, certificate, unmanaged, x509certificate, x509certificate2

Does anyone know how I would do the equivalent of the below C# code using *unmanaged* C++ i.e. query a certificate from the X509 certificate store by thumbprint?

```
        var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.LocalMachine);

        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);

        var allCerts = store.Certificates;

        foreach (var certificate in from X509Certificate2 certificate in allCerts
                                    where certificate.Thumbprint != null
                                       && certificate.Thumbprint.Equals(thumbprint, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
                                    select certificate)
        {
            return certificate;
        }
```

Thanks in advance

Dave

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to accomplish what you want, you'll have to look into the Win32 CryptAPI library. It won't be as easy as .NET. Look into [CertOpenStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376559%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [CertFindCertificateInStore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa376064%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

You'll need to open a certificate store and pass it into CertFindCertificateStore, creating a structure to hold whatever criteria you want to use to find your certificate. You can use a serial number, signature, etc.

```
    HCERTSTORE hSysStore = NULL;
    PCCERT_CONTEXT  pDesiredCert = NULL;
if(hSysStore = CertOpenStore(
   CERT_STORE_PROV_SYSTEM,          // The store provider type
   0,                               // The encoding type is
                                    // not needed
   NULL,                            // Use the default HCRYPTPROV
   CERT_SYSTEM_STORE_CURRENT_USER,  // Set the store location in a
                                    // registry location
   L"MY"                            // The store name as a Unicode 
                                    // string
   ))
{
    //We have our store, let's do stuff with it
    if (pDesiredCert = CertFindCertificateInStore(.....) {  ..... }
}
else
{
    //Error stuff
}
```

You will need to `#include <Wincrypt.h>` and `#include <windows.h>`

Answer (score 0):

The code from [CertFindCertificateInStore.](https://learn.microsoft.com/ro-ro/windows/desktop/api/wincrypt/nf-wincrypt-certfindcertificateinstore) will not work on newer systems. On newer versions of Windows the certificate's name or subject are in Unicode format which uses 2 bytes for each character. The folowing line:

```
LPCSTR lpszCertSubject = (LPCSTR) "Cert_subject_1";
```

has to be change into:

```
LPCWSTR lpszCertSubject = (LPCWSTR ) L"Cert_subject_1";
```

or

```
LPCTSTR lpszCertSubject = (LPCTSTR ) _T"Cert_subject_1"; // add #include <tchar.h>
```

depending on what you need.