# Get X509 Code Signing Certificate Serial Number of signed EXE in unmanaged C/C++

Tags: c++, c, x509certificate, unmanaged, code-signing-certificate

I know how to get the code signing certificate details, including serial number, of a signed DLL or EXE using C# DotNet. For example:

```
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
...
X509Certificate certinfo = X509Certificate.CreateFromSignedFile(filename);
byte[] serialno = certinfo.GetSerialNumber();
```

But how can I do that using unmanaged C/C++?

I did find an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058510/access-x509-certificate-store-with-unmanaged-c) of how to traverse a certificate store in C/++, but not how to get the certificate details of a signed EXE or DLL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example of how to decode an executable's PKCS7 (CMS) data.

```
DWORD dwEncoding, dwContentType, dwFormatType;
HCERTSTORE hStore = NULL;
HCRYPTMSG hMsg = NULL;

// Get PKCS7 data

if(1)
{
    // Must be an absolute path.
    const wchar_t *filePath = L"C:\\Windows\\System32\\ntdll.dll";

    if(!CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_FILE, filePath,
                         CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED_EMBED,
                         CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY, 0, &dwEncoding,
                         &dwContentType, &dwFormatType, &hStore,
                         &hMsg, NULL))
        return 1;
}
else
{
/*  Or do this if you want more control:

    - load exe into memory
    - find the certificate directory (WIN_CERTIFICATE)

    WIN_CERTIFICATE &winCert = ...

    CERT_BLOB certBlob = { winCert.dwLength, winCert.bCertificate };
    if(!CryptQueryObject(CERT_QUERY_OBJECT_BLOB, &certBlob, 
                         CERT_QUERY_CONTENT_FLAG_PKCS7_SIGNED,
                         CERT_QUERY_FORMAT_FLAG_BINARY, 0, &dwEncoding,
                         &dwContentType, &dwFormatType, &hStore,
                         &hMsg, NULL))
        return 1;
*/
}

// Get signers information

DWORD dwSignerCount = 0;
DWORD dwSignerCountSize = sizeof(dwSignerCount);
if(!CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_SIGNER_COUNT_PARAM, 0, &dwSignerCount, &dwSignerCountSize))
    return 1;

// The signer count seems to always be 1.
// Subsequent certificates can be retrieved like this:
// https://stackoverflow.com/q/36931928/2682312

for(DWORD i = 0; i < dwSignerCount; ++i)
{
    DWORD cbSignerInfo;
    if(!CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, i, NULL, &cbSignerInfo))
        return 1;

    PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO pSignerInfo = (PCMSG_SIGNER_INFO)malloc(cbSignerInfo);
    if(!CryptMsgGetParam(hMsg, CMSG_SIGNER_INFO_PARAM, i, pSignerInfo, &cbSignerInfo))
        return 1;

    // Do something with pSignerInfo->SerialNumber

    // Enumerate nested certificates...

    free(pSignerInfo);
}

return 0;
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Here is another [example](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/323809/how-to-get-information-from-authenticode-signed-executables) I came across that helped.

Comment: `if(1)` - Why??

Comment: It wouldn't compile without it, obviously.