# How to read PFX file into X509 in Native C++ and pass this certificate to c# application

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, ssl

I have a client-server application where my client application is in C# (WPF) written and the server application is a WCF service.

Client application uses SSL certificate with WCF service call and WCF service uses the same certificate to authenticate the client.

I am using in C# API `X509Certificate2(byte[] rawData, SecureString password)` to read `PFX` file and pass this certificate instance in each WCF service call. It is working fine.

My requirement is to move certificate creation logic to native C++.
i.e.: *Read PFX in C++, generate certificate object and pass it to C# application.*

`C# Application ---> C++ CLI ---> C++ Native`

Please help me how can I make it possible.

Thanks,
Viralkumar Mistry

Comment: use a library like openssl or crypto++

Comment: Thanks Alan for your suggestion.  i used Openssl but i am facing issue to read PFX as it is created with private key. how to use password with openssl API X509_ptr cert(PEM_read_bio_X509(input.get(), NULL, 0, NULL), X509_free);

Comment: pass a password callback into [PEM_read_bio_X509](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/man3/PEM_read_bio_X509.html)

Comment: Please refer to the below link, it might be useful to you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8058510/access-x509-certificate-store-with-unmanaged-c